# Is it possible to change the value without refreshing the Customizer Edit Window?

Tags: php, settings, partials

I added my own settings to change the font.

This is the code that I got.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'calendar_title_font', array(
    'default'              => '',
    'sanitize_callback'    => 'skyrocket_text_sanitization',
    'sanitize_js_callback' => 'skyrocket_google_font_sanitization',
    'transport'            => 'postMessage',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( new Skyrocket_Google_Font_Select_Custom_Control( $wp_customize, 'calendar_title_font', array(
    'label'       => __( 'Font Family', 'blah' ),
    'section'     => 'calendar_title',
    'input_attrs' => array(
        'font_count' => '20',
        'orderby'    => 'popular',
    ),
) ) );
```

JS code

```
wp.customize( 'calendar_title_font', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        $('h2.toolbar-title')
            .css('font-family', to );
    } );
} );
```

Selective refresh

```
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'calendar_title', array(
    'selector' => 'h2.toolbar-title',
    'settings' => 'calendar_title_font',
    'render_callback' => function() {
        echo get_setting( 'calendar_title_font' );
    },
) );
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to update only the part where the title is located when I change the font, i.e. `<h2>Title</h2>`.  But I still have the full customizer editing window is updating. Apparently there's something wrong with the selective_refresh, I can't catch what it is.

Thank you for your help.

P.S. sorry about my English.

**Edited.** It works for me

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'calendar_title_font', array(
        'default'              => '',
        'type'              => 'option',
        'transport'         => 'postMessage',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new Skyrocket_Google_Font_Select_Custom_Control( $wp_customize, 'calendar_title_font', array(
        'label'       => __( 'Font Family', 'blah' ),
        'section'     => 'calendar_title',
        'input_attrs' => array(
            'font_count' => '20',
            'orderby'    => 'popular',
        ),
    ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to use the same setting_id for which you're using selective refresh.

You can try $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'calendar_title_font', ...rest of the code

Instead of
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'calendar_title', ...rest of the code

Comment: I agree. But it didn't help anyway, the window still refreshes.